# What types of foreign income, if any, are taxed in Croatia for people with temporary residence permits?

Tags: taxes

If we move to Croatia and obtain temporary residence permits (the "renewed annually" type), we would potentially have one of these types of income:

- Rental income from our house in the U.S.
- Standard wage income from a job worked remotely (called "W-2 income" in the U.S.)

Are either of these types of income taxed by Croatia for temporary residents?  If so, which, and at what rate?

Comment: [https://www.porezna-uprava.hr/en/EN_porezni_sustav/Pages/income_tax.aspx] and [https://home.kpmg/xx/en/home/insights/2016/01/croatia-income-tax.html] suggests that they would, at 24% for the first 53k, at 36% above that. I don't know much about Croatia but all this sounds pretty typical for Europe.